# Adding location detail to Google Places via JSON

Tags: java, android, json, google-places-api

I am adding locations to my Android application which is utilizing the Google Places API and when I run a search for these places I am getting the Name, latitude and longitude back but I am unable to retrieve the formatted address or formatted phone number. I am wondering if it is not possible to add location details such as the address, phone number, website etc. or am I doing something wrong. Here is the HTTP post I am using:

```
public JSONObject addPlace(double lat, double lng, String type, String name) throws Exception {
    try {
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Adding Place...");
         String vic = "5/48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont";
         String formtd_address = "5/48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont NSW, Australia";
         String formtd_phone_number = "(02) 9374 4000";
         String myUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=10281119596374313554";
         String myWebsite = "http://www.google.com.au/";

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(PLACE_ADD_URL);
        String postBody = 
                    "{"+
                          "\"location\": {" +
                            "\"lat\": " + lat + "," +
                            "\"lng\": " + lng +
                           "}," + 
                           "\"accuracy\":50.0," +
                           "\"name\": \"" + name + "\"," +
                           "\"types\": [\"" + type + "\"]," +
                           "\"vicinity\":\""+ PlaceAdd.vic +"\","+
                           "\"formatted_address\":\""+ PlaceAdd.formtd_address +"\","+
                           "\"formatted_phone_number\":\""+ PlaceAdd.formtd_phone_number +"\","+
                           "\"url\":\""+ PlaceAdd.myUrl +"\","+
                           "\"website\":\""+ PlaceAdd.myWebsite +"\","+  
                           "\"language\": \"en\" " +

                      "}"; 

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(postBody,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(se);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(post, responseHandler);
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Requested URL= " + PLACE_ADD_URL); 

        return response;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, e.getResponse().parseAsString());
        throw e;
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        throw e;
    }
}
```

So I guess I have two questions. Can you add place details when adding a location within your app to the Google Places API, if so is there something wrong with my code?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions#PlaceReports), Place Reports only support `location`, `accuracy`, `name`, `types` and `language` parameters in the `POST` request. Please file a [Places API - Feature Request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request) if you think that it would be a useful feature to support adding place details.